# SPAの表示速度の目標について

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

AngularJSを用いた管理画面の開発をしています。

一般的なWebページの目標値などを聞くと、
1秒、遅くとも2秒は切りたい。などと耳にします。

これはSPAを作る際でも意識するべきでしょうか？
個人的には管理画面は読み込み後の動作が快適であれば、
最初の読み込みに時間がかかってしまっても問題ないと思うのですが。

目安とすべき時間や考え方などがあれば教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

もはやWeb技術を使っているというだけで、用途はPCやスマホで動くアプリケーションと変わらないのですから、そのように考えればよいのではないでしょうか。

電卓のように必要なときにさっと起動して作業が行えた方がよい場合は起動の速さが重要ですし、ゲームのように多少起動に時間がかかってでもそれ以降の作業がスムーズに行えた方がよいものもあります。朝からずっと起動しっぱなしの業務システムなどでは、なおさら起動にかかる時間は些細な問題でしょう。

そういう意味では、SPAだからどうではなく用途次第と言えます。管理画面にも色々ありますから、読み込みとその後の動作のどちらが多く発生するか、あるいは実際の作業フローを踏まえて、どちらを優先すべきか考ればよいのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

管理画面であれば、初期ロード時間が問題視される事はおそらくありません。
初期ロードさえされてしまえば、あとはネイティブと遜色ないぐらいにサクサク動くので、もし何か言われた場合はそういうメリットを強調するか、初期ロードの時だけ、ロード中表示などを行えばいいのではないでしょうか？